# What evidence is there in the Quoran that Muhammed is the seal of prophets?

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad, prophets

The title says it all. A chapter reference, quote, and translation would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [image: مَّا كَانَ مُحَمَّدٌ أَبَا أَحَدٍ مِّن رِّجَالِكُمْ وَلَٰكِن رَّسُولَ اللَّهِ وَخَاتَمَ النَّبِيِّينَ ۗ وَكَانَ اللَّهُ بِكُلِّ شَيْءٍ عَلِيمًا]
>   [سورة الأحزاب، الآية 40](http://quran.com/33/40)
>
> Muhammad is not the father of [any] one of your men, but [he is] the
>   Messenger of Allah and last of the prophets. And ever is Allah , of
>   all things, Knowing.
>
> [Surat Al-'Aĥzāb, Ayah 40](http://quran.com/33/40)

Comment: Thanks. Great answer. Is this the only place in Quran that this assertion?

Comment: There are many Ayahs conveying the same meaning in different ways, but this is the most direct one that I could think of.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question directly: the already cited Qur’anic passage 33:40 in the only aya in the Qur’an that uses the term “seal of the prophets” (khātamu n-nabiyyīn). However, if you want to pose this as a historical question you need to be aware that in the New Testament (1 Cor. 9,2) Paul writes: ‘If I be not an apostle unto others, yet doubtless I am to you: for the seal of mine apostleship are ye in the Lord.’ The concept “seal of prophesy/apostleship” is a recurring theme in the monotheistic religions. You should also note that there is a lot of discussion both in classical Islamic tafsīr and in Christian exegesis about what “seal of the prophets” actually means.

Comment: Thanks for the elucidation.